# When comparing two Pandas dataframes how to ignore false result on NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I first load two csv files into dataframes. There are some empty values in the dataset as expected:

**df1**

[image: df1]

**df2**

[image: df2]

When I try to compare the dataframes with pandas.DataFrame.eq method, I am also getting False for NaN values.

```
df_1.eq(df_2)
```

**Result**

[image: result]

How can I ignore the false result for NaN values?

Answer (score 1):

Repalce missing values by same value - here `same` string:

```
df_1.fillna('same').eq(df_2.fillna('same'))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

If you compare float values, you shouldn't use `eq` but [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) and set the tolerance 6.999999999999999 and 7.0 are not strictly equal but 6.9999999999999999 and 7.0 are equal (one more 9).

You can use:

```
np.isclose(df1, df2, equal_nan=True)
```

---

**Old answer**

**The code below works only on `pd.Series` not on `pd.DataFrame`.**

Use `fill_value` parameter of `eq` method:

```
df_1.eq(df_2, fill_value=np.inf)
```

Comment: hmmm, I got `f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'`, check docs and no parameter [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) - for you working?